# Cannot close div

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I'm trying to make this persistant cart that lets you add products to cart without redirecting to a new page. It works perfectly, but the only problem is that it can not be closed when you click on the exit button in the corner. [Live version here by clicking on cart](http://eldeskin.com/products/gel-cleanser). Make sure to add a product to see it work, else you won't see anything.

I have tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.cart-show').click(function(){
            $("#cart").hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Aswell as cartToggle with is a feature in the Shopify theme Timber.

Comment: Could not try out your website since my proxy is blocking some requests,but can you try using $(document).on('click','.cart-show',function(){
    $("#cart").hide();
    });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class `.cart-show` is adding to your `[X]` element later, so you should use event delegation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '.cart-show', function (e) {
        $("#cart").hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: This works, but when you close it and you want to open it again, it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click', '.cart-show', function (event) {
     event.preventDefault();
    $("#cart").hide();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) You should use event delegation,

2.) If you have id for element you should use id as selector

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').on('click', '#exit', function () {
        $("#cart").hide();
    });
});
```